# tflearn - access RNN state and feed it back during training

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to figure out how to access the state of an RNN in tflearn, e.g. using `tflearn.gru`. If I train it using `tflearn.dnn.fit` I won't have access of the RNN; so what is the best solution to feed the state back in the rnn after each training step (imagine my sequences are of infinite length; therefore I have to do this to teach the RNN how to use the state).

What are the best approaches to do this? In addition, I can't find any information about whether this is done automatically in general in tensorflow RNNs, i.e. if the state is kept between usages or reset each time (by experimenting I found out that it is reset at each iteration).